# Concurrency::combinable / c++

Tags: c++, concurrency, parallel-processing, factorial

this is code that computes factorial of an arbitrary number:

```
unsigned long long factorial(int n)
{
  Concurrency::combinable<unsigned long long> products=Concurrency::combinable<unsigned long long>([]()->unsigned long long{return 1LL;});
  Concurrency::parallel_for(1, n+1, [&products](int i){products.local() *= i;});
  return products.combine([](unsigned long long lProduct, unsigned long long rProduct){ return lProduct*rProduct;  });
}
```

can u please explain to me:

1. - what does `()->` mean? i think `()` is a functor, but of which class? and why is there `->`?
2. - what is `1LL`?

Comment: [Modern] C++ book required! BTW be careful of seeing `()` and saying "oh, that's a functor". It's often seen when you default-construct a temporary object of some type; but there's no way to know in most cases that the type is a functor type. Often it is not. Anyway, in this case it's something else anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->unsigned long long` declares the return type of the lambda function.

You can google on C++ lambda for more information, but be basic syntax is something like:

```
[capture_mode] (formal_parameters) mutable -> return_type {body}
```

`1LL` is basically the same as `static_cast<long long>(1)`. `1` is an `int`, `1LL` is a `long long`.

However, a shorter way to write it would have been:

```
Concurrency::combinable([]{return 1ULL;});
```

Where the types should be automatically deduced. Note that I used ULL instead of LL to make it an unsigned long long, as in the original code.

Answer (score 2):

`[]()->unsigned long long{return 1LL;}` is an anonymous lambda function returning unsigned long long. The LL suffix indicates that the literal value is a `long long` and not an `int`.